# Problem with debconf when trying to upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, apt, update

I have problem with upgrade my system. When i used command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get an error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
debconf: DbDriver "config": mkdir :Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
Konfigurowanie pakietu debconf (1.5.49) ...
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 44, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in -e at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 46, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 47, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in -d at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 48, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
Use of uninitialized value $directory in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/File.pm line 49, <DEBCONF_CONFIG> chunk 3.
```

config.dat is broken?

```
ls -l /var/cache/debconf/
ls: nie ma dostępu do /var/cache/debconf/config.dat: Błąd wejścia/wyjścia
razem 2184
-????????? ? ?    ?          ?            ? config.dat
-rw------- 1 root root       0 lut  9  2013 passwords.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2234891 sie 19 10:32 templates.dat-old
```

I was trying to reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install debconf --reinstall
```

But this did't help me too...

Please help what can i do to upgrade my system...

Comment: While not *explicitly* off-topic here, as you are attempting to update on the Raspberry Pi, this question might fit better on [unix.se]. That's a Linux/Unix specific site, whereas this site is Raspberry Pi-specific. We would love to help you, but I believe you will get better and more answers on Unix & Linux.

Comment: your SD card is damaged, please reimage a new system, preferably on the new SD card